# ElasticSearch : Combine fuzzy and phrase query results

Tags: database, search, elasticsearch, fuzzy, phrase

I am building a search engine for a movie database with ElasticSearch.

My need is to combine a fuzzy query with a phrase query to have the benefits of the two :

- Fuzzy : tolerate the mispelling
- Phrase : give importance to the position of the words

I am also using the default tokeniser and some filters : asciifolding, elision, lowercase, worddelimitier and a custom stemmer (only for plurials).

This is my query :

```
POST _search
{
  "query": {
      "bool":{
        "should": [
            {"match": {
                 "Title" : {
                    "query": "scoobydoo",
                    "type": "phrase",
                    "slop" : 50
                    }
                }},
            {"match": {
                "Title" : {
                    "query" : "scoobydoo",
                    "fuzziness": "1"
                    }
                }}
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

This is my configuration :

```
PUT /canal/
{
    "settings" : {
      "analysis": {
                  "analyzer": {
                      "custom_analyzer": {
                          "type": "custom",
                          "tokenizer": "standard",
                          "filter": ["asciifolding", "elision", "lowercase", "worddelimiter", "my_stemmer"]
                      }
                  },
                  "filter": {
                      "elision": {
                          "type": "elision",
                          "articles": ["l", "m", "t", "qu", "n", "s", "j", "d"]
                      },
                      "worddelimiter": {
                          "type": "word_delimiter"
                      },
                    "my_stemmer" : {
                        "type" : "stemmer",
                        "name" : ["minimal_french", "minimal_english"]
                }
                  }
      }
    },
      "mappings" : {
        "movies" : {
          "properties" : {
              "Title": {
                  "type" : "string",
                  "analyzer" : "custom_analyzer",
                  "search_analyzer": "custom_analyzer"
              }
          }
        }
     }
}
```

I have to admit that I am not very confident on how I make my query with the "should" and the two queries. So my question is : is mine the correct way of doing the query or could I do better ?

Thanks a lot !
Florent